# Inserting skipped record info in spring batch

Tags: java, mysql, listener, spring-batch

I have a requirement in which I want to log an exception in a monitor table whenever any record is skipped during the batch run.I can generate a unique monitor id using seq.nextval and then insert in the table.

Now i need to insert the same monitor id in my staging table as well, so that its easier to see which record got skipped. Since I'm not a java resource,I'm not sure how will we do that implementation in the batch context.xml.

Any quick solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a logfile which java reads out if the file exists.

Comment: can you elaborate please. I'm not sure how I can do this in the spring batch context.xml